# Batch file parsing text file from UNIX

Tags: android, batch-file, text-files

I'm attempting to write a batch file that backs up files from my Android phone to my computer.  Part of this process is having my phone generate a file list as a text file using the android debug bridge, and then checking this against a text file containing the file list of the 7zip archive I'm backing up my phone to.

The problem is that the file list generated using the android debug bridge doesn't seem to parse correctly.

```
"C:\%USERPROFILE%\adb\adb.exe" shell ls /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/0149BCAA1301701A > androidlist2.txt

"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" l TWRPBackups.t7z > archivelist.txt

type archivelist.txt | findstr TWRP\BACKUPS\0149BCAA1301701A\ > results.txt

del archivelist.txt

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%c IN (results.txt) DO (
  SET RESULT=%%c
  SET RESULT=!RESULT:~83!
  REM Writes the trimmed line to the output file
  ECHO !RESULT!>>"archivelist2.txt"
)

findstr /V /L \ archivelist2.txt >> archivelist.txt

findstr /V /L * androidlist2.txt >> androidlist.txt

del results.txt

del archivelist2.txt

findstr /vixg:"archivelist.txt" androidlist.txt > discrepancies.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%j in (discrepancies.txt) do (
"C:\%USERPROFILE%\adb\adb.exe" pull /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/0149BCAA1301701A/%%j/ TWRP/BACKUPS/0149BCAA1301701A/%%j
)
```

I'm aware my code is a horrible kludge; I'm new at this. But what I'm doing in the first two lines is pulling file lists as text files, from my phone's android shell and from the 7zip archive respectively. After that, I trim down both of them so as to leave only the file names, and compare the text files for discrepancies.

The problem is the last step, reading discrepancies.txt and pulling the relevant files from the phone. I've noticed that if I manually go to discrepancies.txt and replace the linebreaks (go to the end of each line, press delete, press enter), the file then parses correctly. How do I avoid or fix this problem?

Comment: What kind of linebrakes do you originally have: `CR` , `LF` , ` CRLFCR` ..... ? You can see this in eg. `notepad++`.

Comment: CR and CRLF, apparently. Notepad++ shows:
`2013-05-16--10-14-52[CR]
[CR][LF]
2013-05-18--10-59-11[CR]
[CR][LF]` in the file from the android debug bridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it *might* be helpful:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in (discrepancies.txt) do (
for /f "delims=" %%x in ("%%j") do (
"C:\%USERPROFILE%\adb\adb.exe" pull /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/0149BCAA1301701A/%%x/ TWRP/BACKUPS/0149BCAA1301701A/%%x
))
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much! So if I'm reading this correctly, the code now looks for delimiters (the `CR` line break) inside the delimiters denoted by `CRLF`, correct?

Comment: Every `for loop`  removes one linebreak. So two for loops remove 1.5 linebreaks :)

Comment: ... half a linebreak. Well, I learned something new today, thanks again!